# How to configure router so that it allow clients to connect but doesn't allow accessing the Internet?

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, router, internet, ftp

I have a hacked Nintendo Switch and I've set up a ftp server on it. I can't allow it to connect my Wi-Fi, since it will get banned if it has Internet access. But I still want to remote access its ftp server. How can I configure my router so that it allow clients to connect (Switch ftp server and a PC) but doesn't allow accessing the Internet? My router seems only have a feature that allow/disallow client connection. Is there some router or networking device that have this feature? Do you have other suggestions? Thanks.

Comment: A Linux PC with two network interfaces can do the job. It would be better to have another PC which simulates the Switch when verifying its connection are well enforced.

Answer (score 0):

You dont have to set anything in your router for this. Just manually configure the network on your switch. Once you get to the IP address, fill out the ip address and network mask, but leave the gateway empty. The gateway is its access to the internet and by leaving it blank, it will only have local network access.